# JSON not loading

Tags: jquery, json

Having some trouble getting a JSON feed to load from my site.  I'm starting to think something is wrong with the feed itself, since plugging the address into a variety of different blocks of example code doesn't seem to work.

I've tried the examples below, and continually meet with "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when trying to deep drill the error through Chrome's Javascript Console.  Any ideas?

Try #1:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function(){ 
            var url = 'http://www.solidverbal.com/category/clicks?feed=json';
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                // can use 'data' in here...
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Try #2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.solidverbal.com/category/clicks?feed=json",
            data: '{}', // your parameter goes here
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                loadDetails(msg.d);  // msg.d contains the JSON data being returned
            },
            error: function (msg, error, obj) {
                alert(msg.responseText);
            }
        });


        function loadDetails(results) {
            // depending on the data in the JSON object, you can access them using
            // the syntax results.<propertyname>  etc…
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Is solidverbal.com your domain?

Comment: Obvious potential error: `origin null` means you're running this on your local machine's file system. Chrome won't let you do AJAX calls when doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions you are not allowed to perform cross domain AJAX calls. So unless the page you are running this script from is hosted on `http://www.solidverbal.com` this won't work. As a possible workaround you could use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) if the remote domain supports it or supply a server side script on your domain that will serve as bridge between your domain and the remote domain and then perform the AJAX call to this script.